# How to open floppy with fstream

Tags: c++, windows, fstream

How to open floppy disc with fstream?
I'm trying something like this:
but it always returns error

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

char a='k';

int main()
{
    fstream stream;
    stream.open( "\\\\.\\A:", ios::binary );

    if( stream.good() == false )
    {
            cout <<"Error";
    }

    for( int i = 0 ; i < 512 ; i++ )
    {
            stream >> a;
            //cout << a;
    }
    stream.close();
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use fstream to open a device - only a file within the filesystem contained on that device.  You need to use operating system specific functionality to access a device.

EDIT: To be clear, it might be possible to open the floppy device using fstream but this level of access to the system goes beyond the level of abstraction provided by the Standard C++ Library and so OS-specific functions should be used instead.

Comment: Depending on the OS, it may in fact be possible to access a device directly with fstream. The OP should have specified, sure, but it's not _impossible_.

Comment: I've got Vista, so I've to use winapi routines? I think I've saw that mine method somewhere, that's why I'm trying it.

Comment: @bdonlan: So it's reasonable to open a device and access it as a stream of bytes, as you would a file using fstream?  It might not be impossible but it's not useful either is it?  Would you write code to do it that way?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to write first sector of floppy this way.

Comment: @Neomex: Yes look at `DeviceIoControl()` et al.

Comment: @trojanfoe, sure it's reasonable. It adds a buffering layer to your I/O. Hell, the original C file I/O API was designed with a seeking model based on tape drives, block devices are easy. If I had to guess, the OP probably has the device filename wrong or something, but I'm not too familiar with win32 device naming so I can't be sure about that.

Comment: @trojanfoe, what deviceiocontrol() commands would the OP need? Surely even if he/she was using the raw win32 api, only CreateFile and WriteFile would be needed?

Comment: @bdolan: I would say this level of access to the system is beyond the level of abstraction provided by the standard C++ library, so it's much better to implement this using OS-specific functions.  Using `CreateFile()` to open the device means the returned handle can be used in these OS-specific functions, like `DeviceIoControl()`.  It might be possible using fstream but it's not reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

As described in the Remarks section of [this MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363216%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), device files should be opened with `FILE_SHARE_READ|FILE_SHARE_WRITE` sharing mode. By default, fstreams do not support this. You will need to directly open a handle to the file using the low-level win32 [`CreateFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API, then read/write using [`ReadFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365467%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`WriteFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365747%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). When done, close the handle with [`CloseHandle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724211%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Compiler doesn't know _O_RDONLY , _sopen and attach(), what library is it reffering to?

Comment: @Neomex, these are Microsoft extensions. If your compiler does not support them, however, you will have to use the low-level API instead.

Comment: Also it goes without saying that this all assumes you're on Windows. If you're not on windows, then the "\\.\a:" path won't work _at all_ and you'll need to use a completely different method.

Comment: Yes I'm using windows, however both VC++ and gcc, does not know these, with included windows, winbase and fstream.

Comment: You need to include `io.h` for `_sopen` and `stdio.h` for `perror`. However after further checking, it seems that `fstream::attach` was removed after visual studio 6.0, so I guess you won't be able to use it after all.